# Why reloading the page doesn't refresh the form?

Tags: html, forms, refresh

```
<form id="regform" action="regg.php" method="post">
<input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First name">
<input name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last name">
</form>
```

If you enter anything in the input, and refresh the page - the input stays with old content in it.

F5 - reload button - clearing the cache and reload - nothing helps.

The form is refreshed only if I change the url, and then come back to the form's page url.

Maybe it is possible to solve by codding, but can't believe that I must write code for such an ordinary thing. Reload the page should means reloading the entire page, shouldn't it ?
Or I still need the code ?

Comment: What if server-code decides whether or not to fill this particular input based on URL?

Comment: @raina77ow, it's not the case just with server side filled inputs, but with all inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of many web browsers. It's so the user doesn't have to refill all the fields if (for whatever reason) they leave the page. If the form really does need to be cleared then yes, you'll have to force browsers to do that.

But do you really need all the inputs to be cleared every time? Is this really a feature you want to disable?